# return a variable with redirect.route in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a form in `route('users.create')`.

I send form data to this function in its contoller:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    //if form data is wrong:

    return redirect(route('users.create'));
}
```

if form data is wrong I want return a new variable with `return redirect(route('users.create'));` to get in create view. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible :) However since this is a redirection, your new variable will be available in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a failed validation, you can flash data to the session on redirection.

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    if(/* form validation fails*/) 
    {
        return redirect(route('users.create'))->with('newVar', $newVar);
    }

    return redirect(route('users.create'));
}
```

Flashed data can be gotten in your view template.

```
@if (session('newVar'))
    {{ session('newVar') }}
@endif
```